# undefined offset 0 PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I uploaded an excel file which store into an array $allDataInSheet and try to print_r it in the view. This is the result :

```
Array ([0] => 15220) Array ([0] => 15224)
```

Controller :

```html
$file_data = $this->upload->data();
                $file_path =  FCPATH.'kirim_undangan/';
                require_once APPPATH  .'third_party/PHPExcel.php';
               require_once APPPATH  .'third_party/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    

                $inputFileName = $file_path; 
                $inputFileName;
                $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
                $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
                $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet
                $regex = "~\d{5}~";
                $dataexcel = Array();
               for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
               {

                    $dataexcel['to_name']=$allDataInSheet[$i]["A"];
                    $dataexcel['to_address']=$allDataInSheet[$i]["B"];
                    $dataexcel['to_phone']=$allDataInSheet[$i]["C"];
                    preg_match($regex, $allDataInSheet[$i]["B"], $result);
     $dataexcel['to_zipcode'] = $result;
                } 

   $data_user = array(

    'request_Id'     => $this->input->post('id'),
    'email'        => $this->input->post('email'),
    'name'            => $this->input->post('from_nama'),
    'phone'        => $this->input->post('from_phone'),
    'status'                => '0',
    'unique_id'            => uniqid()


       );


            $this->load->model('excel');
            $this->excel->tambahuser($allDataInSheet,$data_user);
```

my model :

```html
function tambahuser($allDataInSheet,$data_user)
    {
        $regex = "~\d{5}~";
        $this->db->insert('request', $data_user);
        $request_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        foreach ($allDataInSheet as $key)     
        {
            preg_match($regex, $key['B'], $result);       

            $data = array(
                'request_id'         =>   $request_id,
                'from_name'          =>   $this->input->post('from_nama'),
                'from_phone'         =>   $this->input->post('from_phone'),
                //'from_address'       =>   $this->input->post('from_address'),
                'to_name'           => $key['A'],
                'to_phone'          => $key['C'],
                'to_address'        => $key['B'],
                'to_zipcode'        => $result[0], //this is where the error comes
                'tariff'            => '0',
            );
            print_r($result);
            $this->db->insert('excel', $data);
        }
```

But I get `Undefined Offset = 0`.

What did I do wrong ? cause the [0] Array is not NULL;

Comment: Give your `array` and when you got the message `Undefined Offset = 0`, show the code you have try not the output..

Comment: I edited my question, please take a look.. thank you

Comment: @RuchishParikh, in my model.. I added a comment beside the error line

Comment: `$print = preg_match($regex, $key['B'], $result); print_r($print);`

Please give me this code's output.

Comment: nothing change @DenizB.

Comment: Did you remove `print_r($result);` line and add my lines instead of? Result shouldn't be same, please double check it.

Comment: Deniz talking to you that print that array and paste it in question so we can identify error easily. @Maii

Comment: it gives me 0111 @DenizB.

Comment: silly of me ! the first cell in my excel file was NULL.. then it gives me undefined offset

Comment: btw, can I just skip the first row to be read ?

Comment: Is '15220' what you should get?

Comment: yes, the '15220' and '15224' is what i should get.. the problem is, the first row in my excel file doesn't give anything that can be preg_match